# Android system image build Error using go

Tags: go, android-source, android-build

I'm trying to build the system image, but the build process fail at very early stage,
mainly it stops at the [`..blueprint/microfactory.bash`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/+/refs/heads/master/microfactory/microfactory.bash) on the line 62 with this error
`"flag provided but not defined: -b"`

Is there anything im missing.

sorry this is my first time trying to build it bear with me.

Comment: stick `set -x` somewhere after the shebang line in that script and see which command exactly gets called and passed that `-b` flag. From the error message, it looks like it's the package `flag` from Go's stdlib, and form the script, it looks like the script is supposed to call a tool called `microfactory`, whose source code is located in the same directory. The source code [appears to define the `-b` flag though](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/+/refs/heads/master/microfactory/microfactory.go#631). Basically, that's all I can do using my psychic debugging skillz.

Comment: that it exactly what it does sorry I thought it was obvious, it copy it into the build directory then it call it, and when it does, it fail and that what i don't get. i need to dig more, thank you soo much.
also your psychic debugging skills is amazing keep it up.

Comment: Are you sure a correct binary gets called? The microfactory source file contains this passage: «If you don't have a previously built version of Microfactory, when used with
`-b <microfactory_bin_file>`, Microfactory can rebuild itself as necessary.
Combined with a shell script like microfactory.bash that uses `go run` to
run Microfactory for the first time, go programs can be quickly bootstrapped
entirely from source (and a standard go distribution).», so to me, it looks like as if a wrong "version" of microfactory gets called—that one which does not support the `-b` flag.

Comment: So, may be this is a hunch. I'd try to add something like `type -a microfactory` to the script somewhere before the block which tries to launch or build the `microfactory` binary.

Comment: you are right!! it was a path problem, I hard code the right path to the file just to make sure i was feeding the right one, and it worked.
it was copying a wrong file the to build directory. thanks sooo much!!!

Comment: Glad it helped, cheers!